# Entity Framework raising exception when parent properties are changed and a child is deleted

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

```
    // The code below generates exception:
    try
    {
        using (var x = new CourierContext())
        {
            Shipment s = x.Shipments.Single(a => a.ShipmentID == 10);
            s.ShipmentItems.Remove(s.ShipmentItems.Single(a => a.ShipmentItemID == 4));
            x.SaveChanges();
         }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     { MessageBox.Show(e.Message); }

     // The code below works fine:
     try
     {
         using (var x = new CourierContext())
         {
             x.ShipmentItems.Remove(x.ShipmentItems.Single(a => a.ShipmentItemID == 4));
             x.SaveChanges();
         }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     { MessageBox.Show(e.Message); }
```

When i delete a child from parent's children collection (using Remove() method), i get the following exception on SaveChanges(). When i delete a child from DbSet's children collection, SaveChanges() works fine. In my case, Shipment (parent) can have 0 or many child (PackingItem). In child table, ItemID is PK[Auto number] and parent's FK is Not Null. My question is: why delete fails when tried from parent's children collection?

I am using EF 6.2 with C# form-based application in VS2017. Domain classes and relationships were automatically created using DB first.
Shipment Table:
ShipmentID [int, PK, Identity]

PackingItem Table:
PackingItemID [int, PK, Identity]
ShipmentID [int, FK, Not Null]

Exception:
The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

I have read about this exception and someone commented the way EF treats composition/Aggregation and FK for them.

Comment: How do you delete the child? Are you removing it from parent's children collection or from the corresponding db set? Make sure you do the later.

Comment: You should use `Remove` from child `DbSet` though.

Comment: I mistakenly mentioned incorrect description. Now corrected it. Please have a look

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27004243/861716) sufficiently describes what's going on here, even though it's about clearing a collection. You may want to mark your own question as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Yes, that's fine as an alternative to get the objective done. But i could not find an answer WHY EF raises an exception when an child is deleted from parent's children collection?

The comment that talked about composition/aggregation scenarios that EF treats, but that is different scenario to keep the child or not when parent is deleted. In my case, i am deleting a child.

Comment: @SyedIrfanAhmad Does it really matter why? It is what it is, there is nothing you can do about it other than using the workaround.

Comment: Yeah, things are implemented the way they are. I can't explain it any better than I did. Explaining is not the same as justifying you know. I'm curious which comments regarding composition/aggregation you refer to. We can't really argue with something we don't know.

Answer (score 1):

### What is happening?

The exception message is a little hard to follow, but it does have all the information you need.

> Exception: The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Let's break this down:

> The relationship could not be changed ...

EF has tried to modify a RELATIONSHIP between two entities. These relationships are stored as PRIMARY/FOREIGN key pairs in the database. Which matches with the next part.

> ... because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value.

Ok, so EF tried to set a FK to null, but there is a database constraint that prevented it.

> If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or **the unrelated object must be deleted.** (Emphasis mine)

This is the solution you end up with, so that will work long-term.

---

### Why does this happen?

Assumption: You have defined the `ShipmentItem` to have a required `Shipment`.

When you write

```
s.ShipmentItems.Remove(s.ShipmentItems.Single(a => a.ShipmentItemID == 4));
```

you are telling EF to remove an item from the parent collection. This is ONLY telling EF to remove the *relationship* between the two objects.

When you write

```
x.ShipmentItems.Remove(x.ShipmentItems.Single(a => a.ShipmentItemID == 4));
```

you are telling EF to remove an item from the database. This is explicitly telling EF to delete the item (and by extension remove it from any and all collections it belongs to).

---

### Why is this the correct design?

Suppose you have a different relationship where a Class is taught by some number of Teachers, but each Teacher only teaches one class.

```
class Class {
    Teachers: Collection<Teacher>;
}

class Teacher {
     Class: Class;
}
```

If we remove a Teacher from a Class, we don't want to delete the Teacher. We just want to end the relationship.

```
c.Teachers.Remove(teacher);
```

EF has no way to know that this remove is any different from your ShipmentItems remove. So to avoid data loss (and BAD THINGS), EF assumes that all items in the DB should stay there unless it is explicitly told to remove them.

Comment: This is *not* a correct design for required relationship. Hence it is a wrong design/implementation which is fixed in EF Core.

Comment: @IvanStoev Can you provide a source for the reasoning behind that decision? Personally, I really like this behavior because it protects against data deletion bugs, but I'm interested to hear more.

Comment: If EF6 would really support aggregates/composition it would *delete* a child when it's removed from the parent's collection. As said, EF core does it right.

Comment: If we assume, EF does not delete to protect data loss, this is even weird for me. It means a design compromise for a usability scenario. A better approach could have been if a setting was provided: keep-and-set-null or delete